# GeoServer blocked HTTP requests issue

Tags: geoserver

When try to preview a layer, got following error related to blocked “HTTP” request:

```
Mix Content: The page at 'http wms service=WMS&vers..tion/openlayers:321s://dev.geoserver .dmp.azure.cloud.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/geoserver/wms servic 58B1&width=768&hei ght=539&srs=EPSG%3A26713&Forma pplication/openlayers’ was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame ‘http://dev.geoserver.dm
p.azure.cloud.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/geoserver /wms ?SERVICE=WM..3659. 3321252958%2C49176
48. 712699675%2C597515 .080901723%2C4921504.461476102". This request has been
blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: there is both http and https (mixed) that is the reason. for azure see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007721/ssl-certificate-not-working-for-my-azure-app-service#:~:text=is%20a%20mixed%20content%20warning,you%20will%20solve%20that%20problem.

Answer (score 1):

after setting Proxy Base URL in global settings the issue is gone.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

the Proxy Base URL to add:

https://xxxdomain.com/geoserver/